# Impulse Response of real coefficient, LTI System

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, frequency-response, impulse-response, homework

I'm trying to obtain the impulse response $h[n]$ of a system whose frequency response is $H(e^{j\omega})=R(\omega)e^{-25j\omega}$. I believed that $h[n]=h[n-25]$, would be the correct answer, however I was told it would be something along the lines of $h[n]= h[50-n], 0<=n<=25$.
Can somebody explain why?

Comment: What is $R(\omega)$? Or is it a typo? Because if $H(\mathrm{e}^{j\omega})=R(\omega)\mathrm{e}^{-j25\omega}$, the impulse response should be related to $r[n]$ at the very least.

Comment: @cjferes $R(w)$ like the a filters linear phase expression $H(e^{jw})=R(w)e^{-aw+b}$, some books refer to It as $A(w)$ I believe

Comment: Not sure if I am correct, but check my answer. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvT-LfSuy_lgYgoyBs0NhOxJj7pmp7AO/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I derived the answer from this link,https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Linear_Phase_Filters_Symmetric_Impulse.html         I am out of my computer right now, so wrote it in my copy instead.

Comment: @Rima Thank you very much I understood the answer given the link!

Comment: @HelpMeBro I tried to derive from the existing equations in the given link, but you need to understand the maths behind the existing equation. Since I am not entirely sure of my answer, you need to cross-check it. Maybe someone else would be able to provide a better explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

It must be added to the problem that $R(\omega)$ is a real-valued, possibly bipolar function. In that case, its inverse discrete-time Fourier transform must be even:

$$r[n]=r[-n]\tag{1}$$

From the given relation between $H(e^{j\omega})$ and $R(\omega)$ it is clear that

$$h[n]=r[n-25]\tag{2}$$

must hold. I'm sure that you'll manage to combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to come up with the desired result.

Comment: So my combining I'll get something like $h[n]=r[-(n-25)]$, $h[n]=r[25-n]$, would this be a correct final answer? Or am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: @HelpMeBro: You didn't state the actual question, so I don't know the expected answer, but I guess you should express the symmetry $(1)$ in terms of $h[n]$, i.e., state the symmetry property satisfied by $h[n]$.